# ¿Este error qué lo ocasiona? C#

Tags: c#

[image]

El error qué lo ocasiona, pruebo de todo miro llaves y tampoco, ¿qué será?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VENTANA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void juegoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nombreJuego = txtNombreJuego.Text;
            string genero = comboGenero.Text;
            DateTime fechaLanzamiento = dtpFechaLanzamiento.Value;


            Juego juegoARegistrar = new Juego(nombreJuego, genero, fechaLanzamiento);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void horafecha_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblhora_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblhf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahi dice, que el elemento no existe. Ya revisaste si en el diseño existen esos elementos? Parece que los eliminaste

Comment: No, se suponen que están ahí, cuando le de al botton registrar se guarden.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código donde creas el textbox "txtNombreJuego"

Comment: Ya lo edité en la pregunta.

Comment: string nombreJuego = txtNombreJuego.Text; hace referencia a un objeto de tipo textbox (supongo); en dónde creaste ese objeto? en el formulario? estás seguro que ese es el nombre que tiene?

Comment: Muestra el código del FormDesign

Answer (score -1):

El `namespace VENTANA` es incorrecto ya que según la solución donde trabajas debería ser Laboratorio 3.